# PowerShell to Combine 2 columns

Tags: powershell

This may be an easy solution but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it or even if it can be done. I have an `XLSX` file that I am pulling data out of that has 4 columns (`Project No.`, `Project Name`, `FirstName`, `LastName`). Using `export-excel`, I am pulling the data out of the spreadsheet, combining half of it and throwing it into a single spreadsheet (so I am combining `Project No. + Project Name` and `FirstName + LastName`). This gives me 2 columns - `Project` and `PM`). Where I am stuck on is I can't seem to get leading zeros into the project number. `Closedproject_new.xlsx` was data dumped with the leading zeros. If at all possible, I need to be able to combine the 2 columns exactly how they are shown in the spreadsheet.

```
Project No. Project Name                        FirstName   LastName
0001        The first project                   Charlie     Brown
0002        The second project                  John        Doe
```

to

| Project NO | Project Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | The first project |
| 0002 | The second project |

Here is how it comes out:

| Project |
| --- |
| 1 The first project |
| 2 The second project |

---

```
$objs =@();
$output = import-excel C:\closedproject_new.xlsx | ForEach {
    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Project = "$($_."Project No.") $($_."Project Name")"
            PM = "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)"
    }
    $objs += $Object;
}
$objs
$objs | Export-Excel C:\ClosedProjects\closed.xlsx -AutoSize
```

Comment: If those numbers are coming out without the leading zeros that implies that they don't actually have them, just that the cells they are in are formatted to display them.

Comment: If you want to force the numbers to have leading zeros you can do that with the `.PadLeft()` method. `"$($_."Project No.".PadLeft(4,'0'))` or maybe, if it sees it as a number not a string, `"$($_."Project No.".ToString().PadLeft(4,'0'))`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - thank you!!! .ToString().PadLeft(4,'0') worked. Did exactly what I needed it to do.